# Ember-Data Custom Adapter

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have written a custom adapter for Ember-Data for use with [Rhom API](http://edgedocs.rhomobile.com/guide/rhom_js).

Here is the code:

```
'use strict';

DS.RhomAdapter = DS.Adapter.extend(Ember.Evented, {

    extractVars: function(rhomRecord) {
        return rhomRecord.vars();
    },

    objectToId: function(record) {
        record["id"] = record.object;
        return Ember.copy(record);
    },

    find: function(store, type, id) {
        console.log('find');
        var record = Rho.ORM.getModel(this.model).find(
            'first',
            {
                conditions: {object: id}
            }
        );
        var result = record.vars();
        result["id"] = result.object;
        return Ember.RSVP.resolve(result);
    },

    findAll: function(store, type) {
        console.log('findALl');
        var records = Rho.ORM.getModel(this.model).find('all');
        var results = records.map(this.extractVars);
        var results = results.map(this.objectToId);
        var promise = new Ember.RSVP.Promise(function(resolve, reject){
          // succeed
          resolve(results);
          // or reject
          reject([]);
        });
        return promise;
    },

    createRecord: function(store, type, record) {
        Rho.ORM.getModel(this.model).create(record.toJSON());
        return Ember.RSVP.resolve();
    },

    updateRecord: function(store, type, record) {
        console.log(record.get('id'));
        var result = Rho.ORM.getModel(this.model).find('first', {conditions: {object: record.get('id')}});
        result.updateAttributes(record.toJSON());
        return Ember.RSVP.resolve();
    },

    deleteRecord: function(store, type, record) {
        var result = Rho.ORM.getModel(this.model).find('first', {conditions: {object: record.get('id')}});
        result.destroy();
        return Ember.RSVP.resolve();
    }


});
```

When a new record is created, the createRecord is called. But Ember does not know the id of the object that was created. Now when I try to modify that object in the view, updateRecord is called and that object is passed but that object does not have an id. So how do I update the backend if I dont know the ID?

Answer (score 1):

The promise returned by `createRecord` should be resolved with the new record (including the id).

```
createRecord: function(store, type, record) {
    var json = record.toJSON();
    Rho.ORM.getModel(this.model).create(record.toJSON());
    json.id = .... 
    return Ember.RSVP.resolve(json);
},
```

Comment: Ohhh!! Ok. Ill try it.